# How do I make a rank with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a rank command with Firebase Realtime Database, but I'm having trouble identifing users' money. Below is an example of what the Json file looks like:

```
{
  "Users": {
    "12345678912345678" : {
      "Economy" : {
        money: 50
      }
    },
    "98989898989898989" : {
      "Economy" : {
        money: 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, I tried something like that:

```
const money = await require('firebase').default.database().ref('Users').once('value')
let entries = Object.entries(money.val());
entries = entries.filter(([a, b]) => b[1]["money"]);
entries.sort((a, b) => b[1]["money"] - a[1]["money"]);
```

I tried to change several things to make it work, but it still doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, but created a bit of a mess with the entries and forgot the `Economy` key. When you add both and clean up a bit you end up with:

```js
var json = {
  "Users": {
    "12345678912345678": {
      "Economy": {
        money: 50
      }
    },
    "98989898989898989": {
      "Economy": {
        money: 100
      }
    }
  }
}
let entries = Object.entries(json.Users);
console.log(entries);
entries = entries.filter(o => o[1].Economy.money);
console.log(entries);
entries.sort((a, b) => b[1].Economy.money - a[1].Economy.money);
console.log(entries);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But now I'm having trouble with the other part of the code. Can you see my last question?